# Method to remove \n\t after web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping using beautiful soup and using pandas I apologize in advance. I am trying to remove the tab and new line characters from my data frame after I scrapped it. The characters are within the string and I cannot seem to find a way to remove them I have been through similar posts but they were not able to solve the issue and I am not sure why.

At the bottom I tried to use .replace to remove the characters but it did not remove them. For the final outcome I was hoping to remove the \n\t characters from each row.

```
#imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as py
import csv

#Getting Website for each game ID in 2023 season
gameID = 598903
while gameID <= 598903: 
    website = f"https://baseball.pointstreak.com/boxscore.html?gameid={gameID}"
    result = requests.get(website)
    content = result.text
    gameID = gameID + 1
    #Convert html with Beatiful Soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

#Get Inning playbyplay Data
Innings = soup.findAll(class_='pbpinning')
#Strip text to clean data
for i in Innings:
#Get Inning playbyplay Data
Innings = soup.findAll(class_='pbpinning')
#Strip text to clean data
for i in Innings:
    #Getting into Array as text is not in homogenous structure
    pbparray = py.asarray([{i.text.strip()}], dtype=object)
    #Fit to Dataframe
    pbpdf = pd.DataFrame(pbparray)
    #Naming Column
    pbpdf.columns = ["Play by Play"]
    #Cleaning \n and \t characters
    pbpdf.replace(to_replace=[{'\\n', '\\t'}], value ='', regex=True)
    print(pbpdf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strip-ping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the text of your BeautifulSoup Tag element won't work because as stated in the docs;

> Characters are removed from the leading end until reaching a string
> character that is not contained in the set of characters in chars. A
> similar action takes place on the trailing end

so, if the characters you're trying to remove happen to be somewhere else than the beginning or the end of the text, then they won't be removed. See the example;

```
"foo\tbar".strip("\t")
# 'foo\tbar'
"\tfoo\tbar\t".strip("\t")
# 'foo\tbar'
```

In your case, you could use [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) instead;

```
"".join([x for x in i.stripped_strings])

'Top of 1stLondon Majors#28  Austin WilkieFoul, 28 Austin Wilkie advances to 1st (single)#21  Tommy Reyes-CruzFoul, 28 Austin Wilkie advances to 2nd (error by the pitcher), Ball, 28 Austin Wilkie advances to 3rd (21), 21 Tommy Reyes-Cruz putout (fly out to right field) for out number 1#35  Cleveland BrownleeSwinging Strike, Swinging Strike, 35 Cleveland Brownlee advances to 1st (hit by pitch)#26  Eduardo de OleoBall, Ball, Foul, Ball, 26 Eduardo de Oleo advances to 1st (walk), 35 Cleveland Brownlee advances to 2nd (26)#7  Starling JosephBall, Ball, Ball, Called Strike, Foul, 7 Starling Joseph advances to 1st (walk), 26 Eduardo de Oleo advances to 2nd (7), 35 Cleveland Brownlee advances to 3rd (7), 28 Austin WilkieScoresEarned(7)#11  Brett GrahamBall, 7 Starling Joseph putout (6-4) for out number 2, 11 Brett Graham putout (6-4-3 DP) for out number 3Runs: 1, Hits: 1, Errors: 1, LOB: 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to change the type of your column to `str` an then write the pattern to replace, Also your pattern is not true. `Series.str.replace()` only accepts `str` or compiled regex as input pattern:

```
for i in Innings:
    #Getting into Array as text is not in homogenous structure
    pbparray = py.asarray([{i.text.strip()}], dtype=object)
    #Fit to Dataframe
    pbpdf = pd.DataFrame(pbparray)
    #Naming Column
    pbpdf.columns = ["Play by Play"]

    # this line change the type of the column
    pbpdf["Play by Play"] = pbpdf["Play by Play"].astype(str)


    #Cleaning \n and \t characters
    print(pbpdf['Play by Play'].str.replace(r'\\t|\\n','',regex=True))
```